# XA transactions using spring and activemq

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-boot, xa

I am trying to prove I don't need the activemq rar deployed to JBoss EAP 6.3 in order to use XA transactions...I'd like to use just the active mq client jar. I created a simple spring-boot project and exposed a method which gets exposed via a restful web service. The following code correctly rolls back if I have the active-mq rar deployed.

```
@Transactional
public void work() throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) this.context
            .getBean("jmsConnectionFactory");

    // Send a message
    MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage("Test message!");
        }
    };

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    System.out.println("Sending a new message.");
    jmsTemplate.send("test-destination", messageCreator);

    throw new Exception("Something bad happened!!");
}
```

However, when I create my own ConnectionFactory via JNDI, the code doesn't rollback and the message still gets sent.

```
@Transactional
public void work() throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    // Send a message
    MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage("Test message!");
        }
    };

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    System.out.println("Sending a new message.");
    jmsTemplate.send("test-destination", messageCreator);

    throw new Exception("Something bad happened!!");
}
```

What I'd like to understand is what spring-boot is doing at boot time to provide XA support when the activemq rar is deployed as a resource adaptor on EAP. If I understand that, I think I should be able to just package the active-mq client jar and my database jar in my spring app (not spring-boot based) and still provide XA support i.e. get spring to manage the XA transactions by delegating to the PlatformTransactionManager.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Will

Comment: Which Spring Boot version and why aren't you using Spring boot... Looks to me if you manually configure everything instead of letting Spring Boot do the auto configuration.

Comment: Hi, I am using spring-boot 1.2.1 to try and prove the point. I would love to use spring-boot. 
However, I am working with a 5 year old system (which uses spring, iBatis hosted on weblogic) 
They are moving the app to JBoss EAP and JBoss A-MQ. They require XA transaction support and 
I'd like to see if I can achieve that using the A-MQ client jar in conjunction with the appropriate XA database driver.

Comment: I'd like to understand how using spring's PlatformManager delegates to the app server when it is present. 
When I use spring-boot I can see the PlatformManager and jmsConnectionFactory beans being loaded. 
However, when I don't use the activemq rar and use the client, the ActiveMQConnectionFactory appears 
to be used and not the ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is all about conventions. You need to indicate Spring Boot that you are connecting to a XA connection factory.
According to Spring Boot documentation ([32.3 Using a Java EE managed transaction manager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_a_java_ee_managed_transaction_manager)) :

> Spring Boot will attempt to auto-configure JMS by looking for a ConnectionFactory at the JNDI path **java:/JmsXA** or **java:/XAConnectionFactory**

Comment: Thankyou Damien. When I autowired the

Comment: Thankyou Damien, when  autowire the defaultConnectionFactory, it works.

// Inject the primary (XA aware) ConnectionFactory
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory;

I

Comment: I also had to use the app server TransactionManager

    @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager()  throws Throwable {
        JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransactionName("java:jboss/UserTransaction");
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManagerName("java:/TransactionManager");

        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }